# Javascript doesn't work without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have the page using ag-grid and some custom javascript for changing a button property "disabled". When the page is loaded for the first time the script is not working, however if I refresh the page it is working just fine.

What may cause this issue? 
Here is the js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.table.data tbody').on('change', '.list-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
            var repCount = $('.table.data tr.republishable input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
            var notRepCount = $('.table.data tr:not(.republishable) input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

            $("#btn-republish").prop("disabled", repCount === 0 || notRepCount > 0)
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that jQuery selector '.table.data tbody' was not good enough. It was too low and as far as there were a lot of data in the grid, so before I found the entries table data was changed. 
So changing the css selector helped.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have what we call a "race condition".

You possibly have `async` on the line where you have included jQuery (something like `<script src="/path/to/jQuery" async>`, I assume it's jQuery, based on the syntax).

Just remove the `async` from this line to make your code work reliably.

Comment: There isn't async anywhere

Comment: It will help if you can share your complete functional code somewhere. (codepen for instance)